# Compile and build chromium browser for electron

Tags: electron, chromium

So I am developing an electron application. I know electron is running a chromium browser in its core.

One of the use cases I am currently working on involves changing the source code of Chromium. I have cloned the Chromium project and made the changes. Now is it possible to use my version of Chromium to build my electron application?

If yes, how can I do it? If no, what are the alternatives?

Comment: You would basically have to rebuild Electron to use your code. This could be achieved by copying your source into the chromium_src folder in the Electron sources and then recompile the whole Electron sources.

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner : Yes I am aware of that. But the directory structure of the source in which I made my changes ([here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/mac_build_instructions.md#Get-the-code) ) and chromium_src are different. Any idea how I can copy?

Comment: @AlexanderLeithner : I want to make some changes to Chromium's content module and rebuild electron. The problem is, there's no content module inside electron's chromium_src.

Comment: It was just an educated guess, I didn't study the directory tree and I have no idea how the people at GitHub are building Chromium for Electron. Maybe create the module and there is a flag in the makefile, for example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I had to basically rebuild the entire electron code.

Get the libchromium source from [here](https://github.com/electron/libchromiumcontent)

To modify the code in content module of electron we have to write a patch in libchromium/patches. 
And then build libchromiumcontent :

```
./scripts/bootstrap
./scripts/update
```

Compile and package libchromiumcontent with the following commands:

```
./script/build
./script/create-dist
```

After the build is done, take note of the hash from the libchromiumcontent commit that includes your patch and perform the following commands, replacing your operating system and architecture as appropriate:

```
# Use either win|linux|osx to reference the platform
mkdir -p osx/x64/<commit>
mv libchromiumcontent* osx/x64/<commit>
```

And then build Electron with our custom libchromiumcontent :

Clone electron if you have not done already

```
git clone https://github.com/atom/electron && cd electron
```

Bootstrap Electron with our custom libchromiumcontent:

```
./script/bootstrap.py -v --url file:///path/to/libchromiumcontent
```

And finally build Electron:

```
./script/build.py -c D
```

Comment: Good question, but it seems these instructions are kind of out of date unfortunately...

Comment: @MattTreichel I did this recently and while the specific commands to execute are quite different, the general approach remains the same. After cloning the Electron repository, a patch file needs to be created under the `patches/chromium/` directory and the filename of that patch file needs to be appended to the `.patches` file. Then, simply follow the [official Electron build instructions](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/development/build-instructions-gn) and you should be good to go!